# Compile errors due to missing queryDSL classes when creating arquillian webArchive with shrinkwrap and MavenImporter

Tags: maven, querydsl, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

I'm trying to write a simple arquillian test to a large project. There are a bunch of QClasses that are automatically created to query the database but it seems that at the time Shrinkwrap.create() runs, those classes are not created yet and the deploy never completes.

MyTest class:

```
package pkg.integration.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.api.maven.archive.importer.MavenImporter;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import pkg.service.TestService;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive getDeploy() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class)
                .loadPomFromFile("/path/to/pom.xml")
                .importBuildOutput()
                .as(WebArchive.class);
    }

    @Inject
    private TestService testService;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertNotNull(testService);
    }

}
```

Execution stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not invoke deployment method: public static org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive br.com.company.integration.service.MyTest.getDeploy()

at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:181)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generateDeployment(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.generate(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:64)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.DeploymentGenerator.generateDeployment(DeploymentGenerator.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.execute(ContainerEventController.java:100)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:92)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.beforeClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:202)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:431)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:55)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:219)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:167)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.deployment.AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.invoke(AnnotationDeploymentScenarioGenerator.java:177)
... 49 more
[omitted]


  symbol:   class QConfiguracao
  location: package com.company.portal.model, /path/to/src/main/java/pkg/portal/service/UserService.java:[124,38] cannot find symbol

 [...  A LOT of 'cannot find symbol' errors pointing to QClasses]
 [...  A LOT of 'cannot find symbol' errors pointing to QClasses]
 [...  A LOT of 'cannot find symbol' errors pointing to QClasses]

  location: package pkg.vo
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.packaging.AbstractCompilingProcessor.constructCompilationException(AbstractCompilingProcessor.java:120)
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.packaging.AbstractCompilingProcessor.compile(AbstractCompilingProcessor.java:92)
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.packaging.WarPackagingProcessor.importBuildOutput(WarPackagingProcessor.java:84)
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.packaging.WarPackagingProcessor.importBuildOutput(WarPackagingProcessor.java:50)
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.importer.PomEquippedMavenImporterImpl.importBuildOutput(PomEquippedMavenImporterImpl.java:49)
at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver.impl.maven.archive.importer.PomEquippedMavenImporterImpl.importBuildOutput(PomEquippedMavenImporterImpl.java:44)
at pkg.service.MyTest.getDeploy(MyTest.java:27)
... 54 more


Test ignored.
jun 16, 2017 8:32:38 PM org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl resolveArguments
ADVERTÊNCIA: Argument 2 for ArquillianServiceDeployer.undeploy is null. It won't be invoked.

Process finished with exit code 255
```

build>:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/db</directory>
            <targetPath>db</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <filters>
        <filter>${basedir}/src/main/resources/filters/${filter.name}.properties</filter>
        [filters...]
    </filters>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>false</extensions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Compila .jrxml para .jasper  -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.alexnederlof</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <!--Força para ser as mesmas versões de runtime-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasperreports.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
                    <version>${jasperreports-fonts.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <!-- mvn backupdb:copy backupdb:restore -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>backupdb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <databaseType>postgres</databaseType>
                <bucketFolder>${company.db.name}/db</bucketFolder>
                <databaseName>${company.db.name}</databaseName>
                <postScript>src/test/resources/db/post_restore.sql</postScript>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>company-jpa-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${company.jpa.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Spec.java</include> <!-- Yes, .java extension -->
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include> <!-- Just in case of having also "normal" JUnit tests -->
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx256m</argLine>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>listener</name>
                        <value>com.company.testng.ListenerDominio</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gmaven-runtime-2.0</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <testSources>
                    <testSource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </testSource>
                </testSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0-beta-2,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>






            <!-- we want to execute specifications -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Specification*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>arquillian-wildfly-remote</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- this is required to get test resources filtered properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

dependencyManagement>

```
<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.shrinkwrap}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-core</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.jboss.arquillian}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.spock</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-spock-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-external-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>company-parent-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

So... What am I'm missing?

PS: I'm executing the tests through Intellij. A `mvn clean package` on terminal gives me a:

```
[ERROR] /path/to/src/test/java/company/service/MyTest.java:[8,33] error: package org.jboss.arquillian.junit does not exist
[ERROR] /path/to/src/test/java/company/service/MyTest.java:[16,9] error: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: Please show all the dependencies and the `<build>...</build>` section of your pom.xml

Comment: @SteveC dependencyManagement and build added. But I still didn't add the dependencies itself cause it's a very, very, long list. Sure this is going to be needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC Maven runner does not honor all plugins but just the common ones. I think that in you case you should use EmbeddedMaven https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#embedded-maven instead of importer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the MavenImporter is probably not the best solution for you - it takes your dependency stack, compiles all classes in `src/main/java` directory, takes all resources and merges everything in the resulting web-archive. It doesn't take into account any plugin that you use nor additional directories.

On the other hand, EmbeddedMaven builds the whole project, so then you can use an archive that contains all necessary classes/dependencies.

As for the error: `package org.jboss.arquillian.junit does not exist` it seems that you don't have correct dependencies on your classpath. Please share your `<dependencies>` you have in your pom.xml file or your dependency tree.